# Python Selenium click google "I agree" button

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape some google data but I first want to click the 'I agree' button that google pops up. This is the script I use to do that:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

search_question = input("Ask a question: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("*Your Webdriver location*")
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

driver.get("https://google.com")

time.sleep(1)
agree = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span')))
agree.click()
# time.sleep(0.2)

search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("gLFyf")
search.send_keys(search_question)
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

The problem is selenium doesn't seem to locate the button and therefore I get a timeout error. (I have tried also with find_element_by_xpath and still not working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you scroll up in the devtools inspector you'll notice that your element is within an iframe:
[image: iframe in devtools]

You need to switch to that frame first, click your button then switch back to the default content (the main page)

```py
driver.get("https://google.com")

#active the iframe and click the agree button
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe")))
agree = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span'))) 
agree.click()

#back to the main page
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

That works for me.

FYI - There's only 1 iframe on the page, that's why the xpath `//iframe` works. If there were multiple you'd need to identify it with higher accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have been agreed,then agree button would not appear. That why it is not be able to find given XPath.

Try this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

search_question = input("Ask a question: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(".\chromedriver.exe")
driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

driver.get("https://google.com")

time.sleep(3)
# agree = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span')))
# agree.click()
# time.sleep(0.2)

search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("gLFyf")
search.send_keys(search_question)
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: No the pop up window is displayed. The problem is if I don't remove the window then the data that are returned later are not complete.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working.
Seems like one of the few elements that are interactive in the popup when you first load the site is the language dropdown, which I found by class name.
Then the Agree button is detectable and you can find it by class too.

```
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(2)
    #finds+clicks language dropdown, interaction unhides the rest of the popup html
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('tHlp8d').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #finds+clicks the agree button now that it has become visible
    driver.find_element_by_id('L2AGLb').click()
```

you should now have the standard searchbar etc

Answer (score 0):

i had some problems with clicking pop-ups and the problem turned out to be with that click().
im not sure that it might be the same issue with urs or not but try changing ur click to this :

```
agree = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", agree)
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried this way (sorry for not mentioning it) and still not working. The problem is selenium can't locate the button

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it didn't change frames here is the soulution code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\gassp\\OneDrive\\Namizje\\Python.projects\\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/'

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="consent-bump"]/div/div[1]/iframe')))
agree = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span'))) 
agree.click()

#back to the main page
driver.switch_to_default_content()


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchboxinput"]'))).send_keys('gostilne')
driver.submit()
```